# How do I add an increment to n array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

For example, if I'm doing a for loop such as follows:

assume the string has been made into a char array already

```
for(i=0;i<somestring.length;i++)

 somestring[i] = somestring[i] + i;
```

why doesn't the previous work?

Comment: Please give us more information as your current question is not complete and (at least for me) not answerable.

Comment: Is that how you have written your for loop?? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `char + int` is an `int` - so you'd need to cast to `char`:

```
char[] charArray = text.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    charArray[i] = (char) (charArray[i] + i);
}
```

Or use the implicit conversion available when using `+=`:

```
char[] charArray = text.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    charArray[i] += i;
}
```

However, generally performing arithmetic on characters is a bad idea. Bear in mind that you can easily end up with unprintable characters this way. What are you trying to achieve?